# Copy s3 files from one user to another user s3 bucket [PHP]

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I was wondering if it is possible to copy files from one users aws s3 bucket to another user s3 bucket using php? I am looking for this solution but cannot seem to find it. Any help would be helpful

Comment: does this answer your need: http://serverfault.com/questions/715553/how-to-transfer-data-between-s3-buckets-of-the-different-aws-account-using-comma/715603#715603

Comment: and for the php part, just use the aws php sdk